# audio search library

Tags: audio

Is there any library or command line tool which allows to do with audio what text search does? That would be to provide a sound clip and a longer audio file and to get the position (in time, for example) of that clip.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about libraries or command line tools, but this will certainly be of more, at least intellectual, interest [Creating Shazam in Java](http://www.redcode.nl/blog/2010/06/creating-shazam-in-java/). I believe you can easily tweak it to your needs :)

P.S.: Shazam is a music recognition service ([www.shazam.com](http://www.shazam.com))