# Search java library for audio processing

Tags: java, audio

I should want to detect frequencies in music with java.

I use [TarsosDSP](https://github.com/JorenSix/TarsosDSP), which work ok, but I'm afraid there no active community (I think).

Is there other ?

On stackoverflow I've seen [Sound processing: mixing two audio files, phase shifting and peak controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15371986/sound-processing-mixing-two-audio-files-phase-shifting-and-peak-controller), [Capturing audio and processing rythm in realtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13661809/capturing-audio-and-processing-rythm-in-realtime), [audio search library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346968/audio-search-library)... but there's no accepted answer, so I try me too.

Comment: You can capture with JMF, and do FFT with [available libraries][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287518/reliable-and-fast-fft-in-java